# Buttons on an animated view respond to clicks even when off screen?

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout, I'm applying a translation animation to it. I'm filling the animation before and after. Visually it works fine. The animation ends by translating the view off screen. But if I click an x,y coordinate on screen that happens to be where the view was at some point during its animation, a button on the view has its click listener fire.

The only solution I've found is to add an animation listener, and when the animation ends, mark the buttons on the (now out of view) layout to visibility=gone, enabled=false. This seems bizarre - the view is no longer on screen, but it's still responding to click events. Is this a known thing, I'm probably not setting the animation up correctly?

Thanks

----- Update --------

I refactored my animation a little. Instead of using animation.setFillAfter(true), I set the layout's visibility to GONE when the animation is complete. Now it doesn't register clicks when off-screen. Still interested to know if this is a known thing, as it'd be easier to simply not have to add an animation listener etc.

Comment: yes it's a known thing. If you set the setFillAfter() to true and translate the view and you have also added a click listener to the view then the view won't get click on the translated position but the original (x,y) position still receives the click.

Comment: Ok, can you add as an answer so I can close this down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translate Animations on lower level API( below honey comb) changes where the button is drawn, but not where the button physically exists within the container. So, you are on your own to handle this situation. For more information about this you can refer to this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html). One way is to actually change the location of the button in the layout(not by animation). Here is how you can achieve this:

```
    params = (LayoutParams) mBtn.getLayoutParams();

    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 400);
    animation.setDuration(2000);
    animation.setAnimationListener(mAnimationListener);
    mBtn.startAnimation(animation);

   ....
   ....

   private AnimationListener mAnimationListener = new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        params.topMargin = params.topMargin + 400;
        mButton.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
};
```

Here by changing the layout params we are changing the physical position of the button.

In your case as view is going off the screen so you just need to change the visibility of the button(View.GONE) on animation end.